# the command "kubectl label pod" execute error

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl

I want to isolate a pod from its deployment. So I execute the command “kubeclt label pod  app= --overwrite” Just like

```
 ✘ yanchampion@yanchampiondeMacBook-Pro  ~  kubectl -n test1 label pod myapp-deploy-848987f4fb-wc5v2 app=newname-debug --overwrite
Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: replace operation does not apply: doc is missing key: /spec/containers/0/env/   : missing value
```

Here is the deployment pod info

```
 yanchampion@yanchampiondeMacBook-Pro  ~  kubectl -n test1 get pod |grep myapp-deploy
myapp-deploy-848987f4fb-wc5v2                         1/1     Running            0                5d8h
```

So What's the problem?

I just want to isolate the pod from its deployment!
Someone can tell me how to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate the pod from its deployment"?

Comment: This pod was created by the deployment

Comment: It is maintained by the deployment. But I want to debug my application code, So I need some operations in the pod. If the pod is seperated or isolated from the deployment, It will not affect bussiness

Comment: If what you are looking for is a debug session, you should create another pod outside the deployment with the same spec as the ones in it. It is not possible to remove a pod from a deployment.

Comment: No  It can be done!

Comment: yanchampion@yanchampiondeMacBook-Pro  ~  ktl -n devops get pod  |grep fiy-ui
fiy-ui-deploy-54f48d6846-lpggv         1/1     Running   0               82d

Comment: ktl -n devops label pod fiy-ui-deploy-54f48d6846-lpggv app.kubernetes.io/appname=myapp-debug

Comment: yanchampion@yanchampiondeMacBook-Pro  ~  ktl -n devops get pod  |grep fiy-ui
fiy-ui-deploy-54f48d6846-kqj8v         1/1     Running   0               2m9s
fiy-ui-deploy-54f48d6846-lpggv         1/1     Running   0               82d

Comment: Can you provide any document or other evidence to support that?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to edit or remove the label from its pod spec:

​
`kubectl edit pod myapp-deploy-848987f4fb-wc5v2`